# Stop Windows 10 calculator from asking me to rate it as an app

Tags: windows-10, calculator

Is there a way for me to prevent the Windows 10 calculator from asking me to rate it as an app? (Other than actually rating it, which I'm not even sure would stop it.)

It actually prevents functionality because it blocks the calculator display.

Comment: You *could* try and rate it, but make sure it's low for having such an annoying nag screen ;).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turn feedback off

Go to Settings

Click Privacy

Select feedback and diagnostics "it's on the scroll bar"

Select Windows should ask for feedback and select Never.

That should take care of that.

If not you can also go to Settings

Then click notifications and Actions

Scroll down you will see the Windows Feedback App

Select it and turn it off.